# What are the coloured pieces inside cupcakes called?

Tags: baking

I have been searching and searching online but can't get the answer. Inside cup cakes, without the frosting, you can find some coloured sweet pieces of "I am not sure what", but they look like pieces of hardened jelly.

What are they called?

Comment: How big are the pieces, are they uniform? Do any of these [pictures](https://www.google.com/search?q=cupcakes&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ei=cN7lU6qpK5HdoASk_YC4Cw&ved=0CAYQ_AUoAQ&biw=1536&bih=731) show what you're talking about?

Comment: @Jolenealaska thanks. the pieces are small cube shaped found inside the cupcakes not on top pf them. the pictures you showed are cupcakes with frosting. The cupcakes I had are without frosting. I am not sure if those pieces are found in cupcakes with frosting on them.

Comment: @Jolenealaska they look similar to this http://www.pimpthatsnack.com/images/projects2/475/08.jpg but are slightly harder than jelly

Comment: Are they like gummi bears, but cubical? Like one of [these](https://www.google.com/search?q=gummi+bears&client=firefox-a&hs=rzO&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&channel=rcs&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ei=nOPlU_u5MYS9oQSfg4D4CA&ved=0CAkQ_AUoAg&biw=1536&bih=731#channel=rcs&nfpr=1&q=gummi+candy&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&tbm=isch) maybe?

Comment: Or one of [these](https://www.google.com/search?q=gummy+cubes&tbm=isch&tbo=u&source=univ&sa=X&ei=-eTlU8PcJtC9oQSjvICYDg&ved=0CHAQsAQ&biw=1536&bih=731)?

Comment: @Jolenealaska are they gelatin cubes but I don't think so. they seem to be dried fruit pieces cooked and dried in syrup. I am not sure. I'll post a picture if possible

Comment: AAH, like in a [fruitbread](https://www.google.com/search?q=fruitbread&client=firefox-a&hs=Kqk&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&channel=nts&tbm=isch&tbo=u&source=univ&sa=X&ei=VPXlU6jpK4PioAShv4HoDg&ved=0CDYQsAQ&biw=1536&bih=731)??

Comment: @Jolenealaska yes yes exactly! what are they called???

Comment: @Jolenealaska just what u find in tutti frutti but I need the corret terminology

Comment: I'll submit an answer for you, now that I know what you're talking about :).

Comment: @Jolenealaska I think just found it. I think it's called succade http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Succade but thanks for your help

Comment: This question has been at the back of my mind for _years_!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In comments, how you described what you're looking for is exactly what they are. It's dried fruit, usually candied or packed in syrup. Commonly seen in baked goods are dried candied cherries, candied pineapple, candied citron, currants and raisins. This [Google Search](https://www.google.com/#q=fruit+bread+recipe+christmas) will show you a lot of examples of fruit used like that. This [Amazon page](http://www.amazon.com/s/ref=nb_sb_ss_i_1_13?url=search-alias%3Dgrocery&field-keywords=candied+fruit+for+fruitcake&sprefix=candied+fruit%2Cgrocery%2C285&rh=n%3A16310101%2Ck%3Acandied+fruit+for+fruitcake) will show you the actual products the recipes ask for.